# load balancing between nginx worker process

Tags: nginx

i have nginx setup to use 4 worker processes but only one of them is handling all the requests. other 3 workers are just idle. here is the screenshot form htop

[image: htop result]

nginx.conf look like this

```
worker_processes  4;
events {
   worker_connections  10240;
   multi_accept on;
   use        epoll;
}
worker_rlimit_nofile    20000;
http {
   include       mime.types;
   default_type  application/octet-stream;
   sendfile        on;
   keepalive_timeout  30;
   tcp_nopush on;
   tcp_nodelay on;
   client_body_timeout 10;
   reset_timedout_connection on;
   .........
```

Server is a EC2 C3 Large machine with 2 CPU cores. any help would be great thanks

Comment: Why do you want that? Obviously the load is not high enough to need many workers, just set worker_processes 1;

Comment: nginx is writing video files (.ts every 2 second) and there is a significant delay between file creation. i think it might be because only 1 worker is processing all the incoming streams and it needs to schedule file operations.

Comment: you can try to set worker_connections to 1/4 of your normal connections count. Say if you have 20 established connections, set worker_connections to 5, then second worker will take the job when first already handles 5. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out `multi_accept on;` which will make one worker accept all incoming connections so other workers have nothing to do.